# how to get query values, using Case/eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query and works fine:

```
SELECT id_categoria, categorias.descricao_categoria, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 1 THEN valor ELSE NULL END) as Jan,
    MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 2 THEN valor ELSE NULL END) as Fev,
    MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 3 THEN valor ELSE NULL END) as Mar,
    FROM `movimentos` INNER JOIN categorias ON id_categoria = categorias.id GROUP BY id_categoria ORDER BY id_categoria;
```

The result is:

[image]

But, at laravel, I can't get the result

```
$emps = DB::table('movimentos')
        ->join('categorias', 'categorias.id', '=', 'movimentos.id_categoria')
        ->select("id_categoria", "categorias.descricao_categoria", DB::raw (' "MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 1 THEN valor ELSE null END) as jan", "MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 2 THEN valor ELSE null END) as fev", "MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 3 THEN valor ELSE null END) as mar" '))
        ->orderBY("id_categoria")
        ->groupBy("id_categoria")
        ->limit(1)->get();
```

How do I use/get months fields with foreach??

```
   foreach ($emps as $movimento) {
                $output .= '<tr>
                    <td>' . $movimento->descricao_categoria . '</td>
                    <td>' . $movimento->??? . '<td>
                </tr>';
            }
```

`print_r($emps)` show me:

> Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_categoria] => 1 [descricao_categoria] => Veterinarios [MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 1 THEN valor ELSE null END) as jan] => MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 1 THEN valor ELSE null END) as jan [MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 2 THEN valor ELSE null END) as fev] => MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 2 THEN valor ELSE null END) as fev [MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 3 THEN valor ELSE null END) as mar] => MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 3 THEN valor ELSE null END) as mar

Comment: is query works ?

Comment: Yes. like the sample

Comment: So the only issue is in the `foreach` accessor?

Comment: Yes. I can't get the retrieved data

Comment: what does `$movimento->jan`?

Comment: I tried, but receive: "Undefined property: stdClass::$jan"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248108/discussion-between-abdulla-nilam-and-incrivel-monstro-verde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selectRaw()` instead of `DB::raw()` will fix this issue.

```
   $emps = DB::table('movimentos')
        ->join('categorias', 'categorias.id', '=', 'movimentos.id_categoria')
        ->select("id_categoria", "categorias.descricao_categoria")
        ->selectRaw("MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 1 THEN valor ELSE null END) as jan")
        ->selectRaw("MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 2 THEN valor ELSE null END) as fev")
        ->selectRaw("MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 2 THEN valor ELSE null END) as fev")
        ->selectRaw("MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 3 THEN valor ELSE null END) as mar")
        ->orderBY("id_categoria")
        ->groupBy("id_categoria")
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();
```

Comment: That would be great if you add some explanation or a general description of the *technic* you used so that the benefit can be shared across anyone who sees your answer.

Comment: @ths missed. I was in rush. Thanks btw

Comment: Great! Thank you for taking my suggestion into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that and response is a Array(object).

```
$datas = DB::select("SELECT id_categoria, categorias.descricao_categoria, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 1 THEN valor ELSE NULL END) as Jan,
           MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 2 THEN valor ELSE NULL END) as Fev,
           MAX(CASE WHEN month(data_compra) = 3 THEN valor ELSE NULL END) as Mar,
        FROM `movimentos` 
        INNER JOIN categorias ON id_categoria = categorias.id 
        GROUP BY id_categoria
        LIMIT = ?
        ORDER BY id_categoria", [1]);
```